# Convincing Agda that a recursive function is terminating

Tags: functional-programming, agda, termination

I'm having some trouble convincing Agda that an argument in a recursive call to a function is structurally smaller than the incoming argument.

I have defined pairs, lists of pairs (representing finite functions as "sets" of input/output pairs), and unions of such lists as follows:

```
data _x_ {l : Level} (A B : Set l) : Set l where
  <_,_> : A -> B → A x B

data FinFun (A B : Set) : Set where
  nil : FinFun A B
  _::_ : A x B → FinFun A B → FinFun A B

_U_ : {A B : Set} -> FinFun A B -> FinFun A B -> FinFun A B
nil U f' = f'
(x :: xs) U f' = x :: (xs U f')
```

I have also defined "neighborhoods" and the supremum of two such neighborhoods:

```
data UniNbh : Set where
  bot : UniNbh
  lam : FinFun UniNbh UniNbh -> UniNbh

_u_ : UniNbh -> UniNbh -> UniNbh
bot u bot = bot
bot u (lam f) = lam f
(lam f) u bot = lam f
(lam f) u (lam f') = lam (f U f')
```

Finally, and most importantly for this question, I have defined a function which, given a list of pairs of neighborhoods, takes the supremum of all the first components of the pairs in the list:

```
pre : FinFun UniNbh UniNbh -> UniNbh
pre nil = bot
pre (< x , y > :: f) = x u pre f
```

The mutually recursive function that causes me trouble essentially looks like this:

```
f : UniNbh -> UniNbh -> UniNbh -> Result
-- Base cases here. When any argument is bot or lam nil, no
-- recursion is needed.
f (lam (a ∷ as)) (lam (b ∷ bs)) (lam (c ∷ cs)) =
  f (lam (a ∷ as)) (pre (b ∷ bs)) (lam (c ∷ cs))
```

It seems obvious that either pre f is smaller than lam f, or that one of the base cases will end the recursion, but Agda understandably can't see this. I have tried quite a few different ideas in trying to solve this, but they haven't worked. At this point, I think that the only way is to use Induction.WellFounded from the standard library, but I can't figure out how.

I've unsuccessfully tried to show that the following data type is well founded:

```
data preSmaller : UniNbh -> UniNbh -> Set where
  pre-base : preSmaller (pre nil) (lam nil)
  pre-step : ∀ (x y f f') ->
             preSmaller (pre f) (lam f') ->
             preSmaller  (pre (< x , y > :: f')) (lam (< x , y > :: f'))
```

I'm not even sure that this data type would be useful, even if I could prove that it's well founded.

When looking around trying to find information about how to use Induction.WellFounded, I can only find very simple examples showing that < for natural numbers is well founded, and I haven't been able to generalize those ideas to this situtation.

Sorry for the long post. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see the whole of the definitions because of some unicode - many characters you introduced get rendered as squares. The basic idea of `WellFounded` is not the proof that some data type gets smaller. The basic idea is that Agda can see `Acc _<_ x` constructed by accessor function wrapped in `Acc _<_ y` gets smaller.

In your case it seems as though `preSmaller` is such a `_<_`. It's hard to judge if that is so, because a lot of text is missing. Then you'd need to construct a function that can build an `Acc preSmaller y` for any two given `x y : UniNbh`.

---

The edited question still misses some of the definitions (like, what is `post nil`. But I get the gist of what is happening.

Your definition of `preSmaller` is similar to the following definition of `_<_` for `Nat`:

```
data _<_ : Nat -> Nat -> Set where
   z<  : {n : Nat} -> zero < (succ n)
   s<s : {m n : Nat} -> m < n -> (succ m) < (succ n)
```

Note that it is different from the standard definition, because both `m` and `n` get bigger. This affects the construction of proof of `WellFounded`-ness.

```
-- may just as well import, but let me be self-contained:
data Acc {A : Set} (_<_ : A -> A -> Set) (x : A) : Set where
   acc : ((y : A) -> y < x -> Acc _<_ y) -> Acc _<_ x

Well-founded : (A : Set) -> (R : A -> A -> Set) -> Set
Well-founded A _<_ = (x : A) -> Acc _<_ x

{-# BUILTIN EQUALITY _==_ #-} -- rewrite rule needs this, if I am not using
-- Unicode version of it from Prelude
<-Well-founded : Well-founded Nat _<_
<-Well-founded zero     = acc \_ ()
<-Well-founded (succ x) = acc aux where
   aux : (y : Nat) -> y < (succ x) -> Acc _<_ y
   aux zero     _                                 = <-Well-founded zero
   aux (succ y) (s<s y<x) with <-Well-founded x | is-eq? (succ y) x
   ...          | acc f | no  sy!=x               = f (succ y) (neq y<x sy!=x)
   ...          | wf-x  | yes sy==x rewrite sy==x = wf-x
```

Helper functions:

```
data False : Set where

false-elim : {A : Set} -> False -> A
false-elim ()

data Dec (A : Set) : Set where
   yes : A -> Dec A
   no  : (A -> False) -> Dec A

_==?_ : {A : Set} -> A -> A -> Set
_==?_ x y = Dec (x == y)

s== : {m n : Nat} -> (succ m) == (succ n) -> m == n
s== refl = refl

is-eq? : (m n : Nat) -> m ==? n
is-eq? zero     zero     = yes refl
is-eq? (succ m) zero     = no \()
is-eq? zero     (succ n) = no \()
is-eq? (succ m) (succ n) with is-eq? m n
...                        | no  f   = no \sm=sn -> f (s== sm=sn)
...                        | yes m=n = yes (cong succ m=n)

-- if m < n and m+1 /= n, then m+1 < n
neq : {m n : Nat} -> m < n -> ((succ m) == n -> False) -> (succ m) < n
neq {_}      {zero}          ()
neq {zero}   {succ zero}     z<        f = false-elim (f refl)
neq {zero}   {succ (succ n)} z<        f = s<s z<
neq {succ m} {succ n}        (s<s m<n) f = s<s (neq m<n \m=n -> f (cong succ m=n))
```

The important things to take away:

The standard definition of `_<_` allows to build simpler proof of `WellFounded`-ness, because it is possible to decrement one of the arguments at a time. A different definition of `_<_` requires reduction of both, and that seems to be a problem. Yet, with the helper function `neq` it is possible to construct a recursion where only one and the same of the arguments gets smaller.

Decidability of `_==_` for `Nat` allows me to build such recursion. Agda can see that the recursive call to `<-WellFounded` is for a structurally smaller `x`, so that terminates. Then the result of that is used differently based on the outcome of equality test. The branch using `neq` computes the necessary `Acc` given the function that `<-WellFounded` discovered for smaller `x`: the function terminates, because Agda allowed construction of such a function. The other branch, where `x == (succ y)`, uses the value as-is, because `rewrite` convinces Agda that it is of the right type.

---

Well-foundedness then can be used to prove a function terminates, by constructing an instance of `<-WellFounded`:

```
_-|-_ : Bin -> Bin -> Bin
x -|- y with max-len x y
...   | n , (x<n , y<n) = Sigma.fst (a (<-Well-founded n) b (x , x<n) (y , y<n)) where
  a : {n : Nat} -> Acc _<_ n -> Bin -> S-Bin n -> S-Bin n -> S-Bin (succ n)
  a+O : {n : Nat} -> Acc _<_ n -> Bin -> S-Bin n -> S-Bin n -> S-Bin (succ (succ n))
  a+I : {n : Nat} -> Acc _<_ n -> Bin -> S-Bin n -> S-Bin n -> S-Bin (succ (succ n))

  a+O f c m n with a f c m n
  ...                | r , r<n = r O , s<s r<n

  a+I f c m n with a f c m n
  ...                | r , r<n = r I , s<s r<n

  a {zero} _ _ (_ , ())
  a {succ sz} (acc f) cc mm nn with cc | mm | nn
  ... | b | m O , s<s m< | n O , s<s n< = a+O (f sz n<n1) b (m , m<) (n , n<)
  ... | b | m O , s<s m< | n I , s<s n< = a+I (f sz n<n1) b (m , m<) (n , n<)
   ....-- not including the whole thing here - it is too long.
```

I am not including the whole construction of addition of two binary numbers (also not an efficient one - just an exercise in proving well-foundedness). The important thing to note here is how the recursion is kicked off, and how it is reused to construct new instances of `Acc` for matching types - here `S-Bin` represents a binary number of bit length at most `n`, and Agda is convinced that `Acc _<_ n` gets smaller, even though it can't prove `S-Bin n` gets smaller.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Everything looks fine on my end, so I may have missed something, but I think I've removed all unicode now.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a definition of `_<_` that seems to be similar to your `preSmaller`.

Comment: In the end I wasn't able to find a way to do this by using this method, and solved it using sized types instead. However, I think the answer is good and thorough, so I have accepted it. Thank you.